# A hyperbolic but nonstrictly hyperbolic linear conservation law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

I need an example of **hyperbolic but nonstrictly hyperbolic *linear* conservation law**, but I am not getting one example in any books that I am studying.

My main book is LeVeque (1) and the only example that I got on this is not linear and made my mind confused, because not being diagonalizable, how can be hyperbolic? I also has searching in other books and did not get any **linear** example.

[image]

once, following the same book:

[image]

Many thanks.

(1) R.J. LeVeque, Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws, Birkhäuser, 1992. doi:10.1007/978-3-0348-8629-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the linear hyperbolic system of conservation laws $U_t + A U_x = 0$, where $A\sim B$ is similar to the matrix
$$
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} .
$$
The matrix $A$ is therefore diagonalizable with real eigenvalues, but not all eigenvalues are distinct. This system is not strictly hyperbolic.

---

The system in OP is analyzed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3177815).

Comment: Many thanks. What do you think about the problem of LeVeque?

Comment: Many thanks for the help with the solution: What do you think about my doubt about the hyperbolicity (not diagonalizable)? Many thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still confused: please, look at the post once again, I posted another image about the question of hyperbolocity.

Comment: @Na'omi The system in OP should not be considered as a system (it would indeed not be hyperbolic as such, since the Jacobian matrix is not diagonalizable). However, it has real eigenvalues, so we may consider a sub-system which is hyperbolic: the Burgers part on $v(x,t)$. The conservation of mass is now considered as a linear conservation law with varying coefficients.

Comment: Thank you, Harry49.